# Jupyterhub AD Integration Error: No entry found for user when looking up attribute ‘sAMAccountName’

Tags: active-directory, ldap, jupyterhub

I am facing issue in configuring ldap authentication with AD integration and I get error while logging in. Below is my config file.

```
c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = 'ldapauthenticator.LDAPAuthenticator'

c.LDAPAuthenticator.server_address = '<ip>'
c.LDAPAuthenticator.server_port = 389
c.LDAPAuthenticator.use_ssl = False
c.LDAPAuthenticator.allowed_groups = []

#set up the template which used to bind the user from ldap directory
#c.LDAPAuthenticator.bind_dn_template = ["uid={username},ou=Admin,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com"]

#Active Directory Integration
c.LDAPAuthenticator.lookup_dn = True
c.LDAPAuthenticator.lookup_dn_search_filter = '({login_attr}={login})'
c.LDAPAuthenticator.lookup_dn_search_user = 'user@example.com'
c.LDAPAuthenticator.lookup_dn_search_password = 'redact'
c.LDAPAuthenticator.user_search_base = 'ou=Admin,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com'
c.LDAPAuthenticator.user_attribute = 'sAMAccountName'
c.LDAPAuthenticator.lookup_dn_user_dn_attribute = 'cn'
c.LDAPAuthenticator.escape_userdn = False
c.LDAPAuthenticator.bind_dn_template = '{username}'
```

While logging to jupyterhub with my user I get below error.

```
[W 2021-03-18 05:02:18.675 JupyterHub ldapauthenticator:275] No entry found for user 'testuser' when looking up attribute 'sAMAccountName'
[W 2021-03-18 05:02:18.675 JupyterHub base:713] Failed login for testuser
```

versions

```
python==3.8.5
jupyterhub==1.1.0
jupyterhub-ldapauthenticator==1.3.2
```

Tried different combinations in configuring the parameters but the error remains the same.
`c.LDAPAuthenticator.lookup_dn_search_user` is the ldap account that I have mentioned. Is it the correct way?

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Do you know the full dn of the user(s) you are trying to authenticate (please share it) ?

Comment: Yes I have given the full dn in `c.LDAPAuthenticator.user_search_base` which is `ou=Accounts,ou=Admin,ou=Groups,DC=totalit,DC=com`. I have actually modified it in the question.

Comment: A full user dn would be `cn=<cn>,ou=Accounts,ou=Admin,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com` (<user_dn_attr.> + <search_base>). Maybe it's a typo but the `ou=Accounts,` part is missing in your post.

Comment: I have tried by including `cn` value also but the error is the same.

Comment: I gave an example, how would I know ? My question was do you know the full dn of the user(s) you are trying to authenticate ?